# Identifying grid number by lat, long

Tags: qgis, mmqgis, leaflet-r

I have created a `1km * 1km` grid in QGIS using the MMQGIS plugin and below is a sample of shp@data and the layer

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

Is there a way to do a spatial join on the grid created?

I assume some grids should have more individual points (lat/long) and some should have no point data within them. I want to be able to identify the `"grid_id"` and the points present in the polygon such that I can then join the individual point data like below for e.g. in the below-aggregated data, which grid number does the lat and long belong to `head(b)`

```
Lat                Long     Num.CT   Num.SuccessCT Num.FailedCT Failure.rate
49.91222         -6.302522      1             1            0       0     
49.91251         -6.299382      1             1            0       0      
49.91440         -6.315690      1             1            0       0    
49.91443         -6.309872      1             1            0       0   
49.91501         -6.311369      1             0            1       1  
49.91502         -6.310905      1             1            0       0
```

I tried joining the shapefile with the aggregated data. However, I can't get my head around how to plot and how would leaflet package in R identify the square

Spatial_join_by_location
shapefile join aggregated data

[image: example3]

**Output post joining the point layer and polygon layer**

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GIS SE!

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you are requesting two separate issues:

1. how to associate each point with the ID of the tile it falls in
2. how to count/perform stats on the points contained in each tile

### Associate each point with the ID of the tile it falls in

`Toolbox` -> `Join attribute by location`

- `Input layer`: choose the point layer
- `Overlay layer`: choose the grid (of course it must by a polygon grid, i.e. each tile must define an area)
- select `contained` as `Geometric predicate` (you want to associate each point with the grid tile they are *contained* in)

[image: Join attribute by location]

A new point layer is created, with the containing tile fields (including the IDs, in this case `id_2`) as added attributes:

[image]

You can then use `id_2` to do the joins and calculations in R.

### Count/perform stats on the points contained in each tile

`Toolbox` -> `Join attributes by location (summary)`

In this case you want to count how many points are contained in each tile, and have the stats calculated for you:

[image: Join attributes by location (summary)]

Comment: Many thanks for this , But some how i don't get an id field post joining within point layer and polygon grid layer. I have attached a snapshot of join outcome Can you help me with interpreting it correctly. I want to be able to say  grid 1 - points that fall in it. What i see at the moment ( correct me if wrong ) .. Each lat /long fall in which polygon however each polygon doesnt have an id. So similar left/bottom/right/top should be labelled as GRID -1 ....

Comment: I see, probably the original grid does not have an ID? In the second screenshot of your question there are only 4 fields (left bottom, right, top). If an unique ID field is missing, create it, and then re-run the join.

Comment: @I created the orignal grid as - Upload the CSV file with my lat/long information - create a grid layer on top -  Create MMQGIS grid - X=0.1Y=0.1 unit = layer_units , Layer extent the same as lat /long in my file and saved it as shape file. I check now and the grid file created has only left , right, bottom  ,top and no id , Can you suggest any other way to create an id label in my custom aggregated dataset

Comment: Does each latitude and longitude gets a unique id ? I can label them in numeric column. But when there are multiple lat/long having the same co-ordinates how should i deal with labelling them

Comment: make a new field (integer data type) and fill it with `@row_number`